# React.js: Error using the Link component from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When using the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` I encounter a incoherent error related to the usage of context.

[image: error output]

This happens as soon as I import the `Link` component and try to use it in my `App.js` file, if I remove the import; The error disappears too.

```js
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <h1>Hello StackOverflow!</h1>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly recommend checking out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation. Maybe familarize yourself with the do's and don'ts of posting on Stack Overflow. For example, you should [avoid posting code or errors as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8003058). Instead, you should post the code or error(s) as text. This makes it easier for others to read and understand your code.